# Notarizing a signature for a document to be sent to the US (AZ) while in France

Tags: usa, france, documentation

I need to get a certified copy of my Arizona driving record. This requires me to complete [this form](http://azdot.gov/docs/default-source/mvd-forms-pubs/46-4416.pdf) and send it to the Arizona Motor Vehicle Division (AZ MVD) along with a check. The form unfortunately requires a notarized signature. I see that I can theoretically go to the US embassy in Paris or the consulate in Lyon, but those are expensive (50USD) and time consuming, as I don't live in those cities. Plus I would need an appointment, and I need to send this document out as soon as possible.

I called the AZ MVD and spoke to a level-1 (the lowest level) representative to see if there was any way around this notary requirement. She was pretty sure I could get a seal from a French notary. She also said I could go to a motor vehicle office here. I'm pretty certain that the second option won't get me anywhere. Could she be right about the first (or even the second)?

I've read a bit online and it seems that the French notaries have more power than American notaries, but it seems that they can still certify signatures. But will the seal resemble what they are used to seeing at the AZ MVD and are they likely to accept such a document? If not, what's the quickest way to get what I need without leaving my town (Chalon-sur-Saône)?

Comment: Related: [Travel.SE Question - Finding a notary in France / Italy](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/finding-a-notary-in-france-italy)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you would probably be better off with the embassy or consulate ([Lyon](http://lyon.usconsulate.gov/service.html) may be closer to you than Paris?).

Another way is to use a French notary and have it "[apostilled](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F1400.xhtml#N1007E)" ([Arizona issues apostilles](http://www.azsos.gov/business_services/notary/apostille.htm), and must thus also recognize foreign ones), but depending on the clerk (DMV, after all...) it may cause problems just because they won't know what to do with that...